# 3D arrow head not at the end of the shaft

Tags: bugs, graphics3d

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and fixed in version 13.0.0**

---

Why when I use:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.1],Arrow[Tube[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 0}}, 0.05]]}]
```

which I copied from the wolfram website the arrow head doesn't seem to be at the end of the arrow's shaft. Anyway to correct that? Even in the wolfram documentation the arrow is displayed in the same way. The picture bellow is for both their output and mines

[image]

Comment: use the second argument of `Arrow` with a negative value: `Arrow[Tube[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 0}}, 0.05],-.2]`?

Comment: That worked, thanks! not sure what that argument is doing though.

Comment: I looked back at older notebooks where I had PDF exports to compare to. The arrows looked fine there. But in version 11.3 I see the issue reported here in all arrows with tubes. So this must be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Arrow` with a negative setback value in the second argument:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.1], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 0}}, 0.05],-.2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the setback parameter can be provided as a list: {s1,s2} where the first one applies to the beginning (tail) of the arrow and the second applies to the end (head) of the arrow. If you only supply one value, that value is applied to both ends.

Comment: Good points, thank you @user7739.

Comment: Should we add the bug tag to the question?

Comment: @Jens, yes, it does look like a bug.